# Как правильно настроить Git?

Tags: git, github

Я 1 разработчик проекта. Подскажите, правильно ли я представляю процесс работы:

1. Создаю репозиторий на локалке.
2. Заливаю файлы на удалённый репозиторий GitHub.
3. С удалённого репозитория клонирую файлы на хостинг.
4. Во время разработки, на локалке делаю коммиты и заливаю на GitHub.
5. С GitHub при помощи fetch добавляю коммиты на хостинг

Comment: Почему именно github?

Comment: Думаю в этом вопросе это последнее, на что стоит обращать внимание. GitHub удобней было писать как сокращение удалённого репозитория

Comment: Можно репозиторий сразу создать на удаленке, залить на локалку его пустое содержимое и дополнить своими файлами проекта, и далее по Вашей схеме. Для работы как одного разработчика вполне себе годно, но я бы на Вашем месте еще бы озаботился такими вещами, как docker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы решили работать с удаленным репозиторием, то предложу один из распространенных подходов к его созданию:

1) Выберите сервис, на котором будет размещен ваш удаленный репозиторий (`GitLab`, `BitBucket`, `GitHub` или любой другом);

2) Через веб интерфейс сервиса создайте репозиторий, с этим не должно быть сложностей;

3) Затем на локальной машине клонируйте ваш вновь созданный репозиторий `git clone [url]`;

4) Локальный, как и удаленный репозиторий пока не содержат файлов. Перенесите сюда необходимые файлы, либо создайте их локально;

5) Добавляйте новые файлы в индекс `git add [file_name]` и фиксируйте `commit`;

6) Отправляйте изменения на сервер (команда `git push`).

Если вы единственный разработчик и работаете с одной машины, то дальнейший ворк-флоу невероятно простой - вносите изменения, добавляйте их в коммиты и снова пушьте.

Еще проще - можете без удаленного сервера создать локальный репозиторий командой 
`git init`. Это полноценный пустой репозиторий, также вносите в него файлы, делайте правки и комитьте. В этом случае вам не нужно выполнять команды `git push` / `git pop` / `git pull --rebase`, тк у вас всегда актуальное состояние репы.

В любой подходящий момент сможете отправить репозиторий на сервер и начать с ним работать командой или в одиночку с нескольких устройств.

При командной работе воркфлоу выглядит сложнее, тк в ходе совместной работы правки на сервер вносятся несколькими членами команды и могут вступать в конфликты. В этом случае вам уже нужно будет начинать рабочий день с выкачивания изменений `git fetch`, выполнять ребейз ветки перед отправкой коммита/коммитов на сервер `git pull --rebase origin [branch_name]` с возможным разрешением конфликтов и проверкой работоспособности вашего проекта и только после этого выполнять `git push origin [branch_name]`